# Rename excel file with os.rename() Python

Tags: python

I was writing a quick script which would change the names of every excel file located in a directory:

```
[...]
for file_ in os.listdir(path):
   if 'Analytics Android' in file_:
      os.rename(file_, 'Android Orders.xlsx')
```

But, I get an error: `[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified.` Shouldn't the `rename` function change the name to the second argument?

Comment: You've given the function a wrong path. That's what the error means.

Comment: Your next problem will be that you are trying to give all of your new files the same name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.listdir` does not give absolute paths, but relative paths to the given path to list, so you'll still have to create the full path:

```
for file_ in os.listdir(path):
    if 'Analytics Android' in file_:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file_), os.path.join(path, 'Android Orders.xlsx'))
```

Comment: You need to add path to 'Android Orders.xlsx' also or it will be moved to your current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the absolute path to the file.

```
>>> os.rename(os.path.join(path, file_), 'Android Orders.xlsx')
```